# TemplateListener error when trying to Symfony 3.4 beta3

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, symfony3.x

I'm trying to migrate from Symfony 3.3.10 to Symfony 3.4 beta3. I have the following error:

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::__construct() must be an instance of Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Templating\TemplateGuesser, instance of ContainerWhrfjwe given, called in /home/coil/workspace/project/api/var/cache/dev/ContainerWhrfjwe/getDebug_EventDispatcherService.php on line 21

Here is what I have modified in my `composer.json` file:

```
"symfony/symfony": "v3.4.0-BETA3",
"symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.6.4",
"sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.0.0",
```

Before:

```
"symfony/symfony": "3.3.*",
"symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3.10",
"sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
```

([other lines where indentical](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/v3.4.0-BETA3/composer.json))

The composer command works without error. But every pages raises this error. (even with CLI)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First - as usual, clear the dev-cache, and then try as it says on [Upgrading a Minor Version](http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/upgrade_minor.html):

```
composer update symfony/symfony --with-dependencies
```

It may also be useful to run

```
composer outdated
```

to see what other bundles, at least listed on the top-level, are out of date as well.

Comment: I think I add an error in json and symfony/symfony": was set to "v3.4.0-BETA1 instead of BETA3. Didn't know about `composer outdated`, very useful indeed! It should be launched after or before each composer update. Thanks!